# Can't find what I installed

Tags: software-installation

I installed kdiff3qt through the synaptic package manager but now I can't find it. I've looked in the Ubuntu Software Center and it shows that it (and kdiff3-doc) was installed but I can't find it anywhere. Any suggestions on how to find it?

Comment: have you tried **dpkg -L kdiff3qt** from terminal?

Comment: Have you tried the commands locate, where, which or find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try typing `kdiff` in a terminal and let it auto-complete by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>, and press enter. If nothing happens, press <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice to see your options. Usually when you install a package like this, the binary for that package has a similar name to the package itself. Not always, but it's a good place to start.

If you want to create a shortcut on your desktop, all you really need to know is what command launches the application. Right click, create a shortcut, fill in the name of the shortcut and what command to run. This is roughly how it's done in XFCE anyway. Usually icons are available automatically, sometimes you need to find them manually (or even download them yourself).

Comment: Found it via kdiff tab enter. Actually it brought up Kdiff itself. But I couldn't figure out how to create the shortcut (and what command I would use). I can use it now--thx--but still don't know where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Installed-Size} \t\t ${Package}\n' | sort -nr | less
```

This query will show you all installed packages whith package size in sorted format.